# Installation of GANet

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to use the following NN:

[GANet](https://github.com/feihuzhang/GANet)

This error happening when I doesn't use apex

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 187, in <module>
    test(leftname, rightname, savename)
  File "predict.py", line 158, in test
    prediction = model(input1, input2)
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 141, in forward
    return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/models/GANet_deep.py", line 396, in forward
    g = self.conv_start(x)  
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 92, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/models/GANet_deep.py", line 42, in forward
    x = self.bn(x)
  File "/home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/libs/sync_bn/modules/sync_bn.py", line 121, in forward
    self.activation, self.slope).view(input_shape)
  File "/home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/libs/sync_bn/functions/sync_bn.py", line 95, in forward
    y = sync_bn_gpu.batchnorm_forward(x, _ex, _exs, gamma, beta, ctx.eps)
RuntimeError: cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess ASSERT FAILED at src/gpu/sync_bn_cuda.cu:289, please report a bug to PyTorch. (BatchNorm_Forward_CUDA at src/gpu/sync_bn_cuda.cu:289)
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x45 (0x7fca7ac1bcc5 in /home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: BatchNorm_Forward_CUDA(at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, at::Tensor, float) + 0x2be (0x7fca76e56ff1 in /home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/libs/sync_bn/build/lib/sync_bn_gpu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x22ab3 (0x7fca76e54ab3 in /home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/libs/sync_bn/build/lib/sync_bn_gpu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x201a5 (0x7fca76e521a5 in /home/master/Work/Project01/GANet/libs/sync_bn/build/lib/sync_bn_gpu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
<omitting python frames>
frame #11: THPFunction_apply(_object*, _object*) + 0x5a1 (0x7fcaab0b4bf1 in /home/master/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
```

following the installation recommendations:
[image]

I installed apex, the only installation that worked for me is:

```
pip uninstall apex
rm -rf apex

git clone https://github.com/ptrblck/apex.git
cd apex
git checkout apex_no_distributed
pip install -v --no-cache-dir ./
```

[source](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/429)

with apex (and replacing all the BatchNorm2d and BatchNorm3d to apex.parallel.SyncBatchNorm) the NN running but return all zeros result matrix.
Any suggestions?

Working on ubuntu 18.04
with conda,
python 3.7.4,
torch 1.0.0,
cuda 10.2

gcc 7.5